# move Constraint Layout programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I want to move a ConstraintLayout programmatically. I looked through some solutions on stack overflow but they didn't work for me.

There are two ConstraintLayouts placed vertically. When the code goes into `else if("android.permission.CAMERA" in permissionList.toString()`, the above constraint layout (layoutLocation) will be invisible and the below constraint layout (layoutCamera) will come up and take its position. I mark where I should use declare it with 'want to use here'.

Code (apology to not ba able to post the whole code due to patent reason)

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var mContext: MainActivity

private lateinit var binding : FragmentSplashBinding
private val viewModel : SplashViewModel by inject()
private val getPermissionUseCase : GetPermissionUseCase by inject()

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    mContext = context as MainActivity
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false)
    return binding.root
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

}




private fun actionApplicationSetting(permissionList : List<String>) {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_splash, null)
    val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.CustomAlertDialog).setView(view).create()
    val layoutLocation : ConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_box_location)
    val layoutCamera : ConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_box_camera)
    
    for(permission in permissionList) {
        if("android.permission.CAMERA" in permissionList.toString() && "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" in permissionList.toString()) {
            layoutLocation.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.auth_level_blue)
            layoutCamera.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.auth_level_blue)
        }else if("android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" in permissionList.toString()) {
            layoutLocation.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.auth_level_blue)
        }else if("android.permission.CAMERA" in permissionList.toString()) {
            layoutLocation.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            // want to use here
        }
    }
    alertDialog.show()

}

}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_wrapper"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/layout_wrapper"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout_wrapper">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_box_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_box_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_box_location" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Change `View.INVISIBLE` to `View.GONE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `layoutLocation.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` try `layoutLocation.visibility = View.GONE`